# How do I read the contents of a file from Cloud Storage within a Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage

How can I read the contents of a text file from an [HTTP onCall function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/firebase-functions.https#httpsoncall)? My goal is to read the file as a string, then extract all email addresses from the string and then return the resulting array of emails. But I'm running into issues reading the file.

Note that I know ahead of time where the file resides in cloud storage. I.e. I know the path is `users/${context.auth.uid}/customers`

**Here's what I've tried**

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions')
const admin = require('firebase-admin')
const { getAuth } = require('firebase-admin/auth')
const { getStorage } = require('firebase-admin/storage')
const { readFile } = require('fs')

admin.initializeApp()
const db = admin.firestore()
const bucket = getStorage().bucket()


exports.readCSVFile = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Read text file and identify email addresses within it
  // Return array of email addresses

  const file = bucket.file(`users/${context.auth.uid}/customers`)
  return file.exists().then(async (data) => {
    if (data[0]) {
      return readFile(file.createReadStream(), "utf8", function(err, contents) {
        if (err) {
          throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
            'internal',
            "Could not read customers file"
          ) 
        } else {
          console.log("contents", contents)
          return contents
        }
      })
    } else {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
        'not-found',
        "customers file not found"
      ) 
    }
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.error(`Error: ${err}`)
  })
})
```

This gives me the error

> Error: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string or an instance of Buffer or URL. Received an instance of PassThroughShim

Comment: `users/${context.auth.uid}/customers` should be the file's URL instead of website page's URL

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [`file.download()`](https://googleapis.dev/nodejs/storage/latest/File.html#download-examples).

```
function createRethrowAsHttpsErrorCallback(code, message, details) {
  return (err) => {
    console.error(`[${code}]${message ? " " + message + "." : ""}. Original:`, err);
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(code, message, details);
  }
}

exports.readCSVFile = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  // Read text file and identify email addresses within it
  // Return array of email addresses

  const file = bucket.file(`users/${context.auth.uid}/customers`);
  
  const [exists] = await file.exists();
  if (!exists) {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError(
      "not-found",
      "customers file not found"
    );
  }

  const [contents] = await file.download()
    .catch(createRethrowAsHttpsErrorCallback(
      "internal",
      "Could not read customers file"
    ));

  // if here, contents now contains the data of the file
})
```